# Pandas: Separate rows based on values in one column and convert value in different columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Here's my data. Note that I simplified this table just to understand the problem (my real table has many rows and many different columns).

| REF | ALT | Sample1 | Sample2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C,D | 0/1 | 1/2 |
| B | E,F,G | 3/0 | 2/3 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"REF":{"0":"A","1":"B"},"ALT":{"0":"C,D","1":"E,F,G"},"Sample1":{"0":"0\/1","1":"1\/2"},"Sample2":{"0":"3\/0","1":"2\/3"}})
```

**Background:**
0 Indicates for an element from REF, 1 indicates for the first element from ALT, 2 indicates for the second element from ALT, and so on... it can be more than 3. So, in [row 1,Sample1] there will be A,C (0/1) in [row1, Sample2] there will be C,D, in [row2,Sample1] there will be G,B (3/0) and finally in [row2,Sample2] there will be F,G (2/3).

**Data conversion:**
What I need to do is to split these rows, so that multiple elements in ALT will be located in separated rows and numbers should be updated accordingly. Because there is only one element in ALT now, numbers in Sample1 and Sample2 should be updated. Here's the example:

| REF | ALT | Sample1 | Sample2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 0/1 | 1/1 |
| A | D | . | 1/1 |
| B | E | . | . |
| B | F | . | 1/1 |
| B | G | 1/0 | 1/1 |

I found the way how to separate ALT to multiple rows:

```
def split_dataframe_rows(df,column_selectors, row_delimiter):
    # we need to keep track of the ordering of the columns
    def _split_list_to_rows(row,row_accumulator,column_selector,row_delimiter):
        split_rows = {}
        max_split = 0
        for column_selector in column_selectors:
            split_row = row[column_selector].split(row_delimiter)
            split_rows[column_selector] = split_row
            if len(split_row) > max_split:
                max_split = len(split_row)
            
        for i in range(max_split):
            new_row = row.to_dict()
            for column_selector in column_selectors:
                try:
                    new_row[column_selector] = split_rows[column_selector].pop(0)
                except IndexError:
                    new_row[column_selector] = ''
            row_accumulator.append(new_row)

    new_rows = []
    df.apply(_split_list_to_rows,axis=1,args = (new_rows,column_selectors,row_delimiter))
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns=df.columns)
    return new_df
```

but I don't how I can update numbers in Sample1 and Sample2

Comment: please provide `df.to_json()` of your data frame `df`. So that we don't have to type around for the data.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim, Here's json of my initial data {"REF":{"0":"A","1":"B"},"ALT":{"0":"C,D","1":"E,F,G"},"Sample1":{"0":"0\/1","1":"1\/2"},"Sample2":{"0":"3\/0","1":"2\/3"}}